# Setting Angular HttpClient request headers when called with an HttpRequest object

Tags: angular, authorization, angular5, httprequest, httpclient

When I want to append headers to a standard `get`, `post`, `put` or `delete` request, I can easily pass it inside the `options` object:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

this.httpClient.get<any>(
  'http://myapi.com/endpoint',
  httpOptions
)
```

However, when I am using the `request<R>(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<R>>;` method of `HttpClient`, I am unable to pass any headers in anywhere as it doesn't accept any other parameters. I need to make my request this way since I need to append a file object to the body. This is the way I make the call:

```
this.httpClient.request(
  new HttpRequest(
    'POST',
    'http://myapi.com/endpoint',
    formData, // contains file object
  )
);
```

Is there a way to work this around?

Comment: The headers go in the `HttpRequest` object itself https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

Comment: @user184994 That property seems read-only.

Comment: You can set it in the constructor. I've added an example below for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest), you can add the headers into the `HttpRequest` object itself, like so

```
new HttpRequest(
  'POST',
  'http://myapi.com/endpoint',
  formData, // contains file object
  {
    headers: myHeaders
  }
)
```